# CSS blur a portion of background image

Tags: css, blur

I have the following HTML/CSS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #image {
                background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg);
                display:block;
                width:100%;
                height:500px;
                position:relative;
                background-size:cover;
            }
            #blur {
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
                width: 300px;
                height:300px;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
                border-radius:150px;
                -webkit-filter:blur(10px); filter: blur(10px); -moz-filter:blur(30px); -ms-filter: blur(10px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image">
            <div id="blur"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want the middle of the image to be blurred into a dot.  If I change the background color of `#blur` to blue, I can see that it exists.  But the circle blur isn't happening.

Any suggestions on how to get a blurred circle in the picture via CSS ?

Comment: Try `display:none` instead of block on #blur.

Comment: That removes the blur entirely

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround / solution:**

You'll have to apply a blur to the initial image to blur it, since you can't apply it to a specified spot, we'll just have to use an overlay- blur this and resize it. We can use your dot pretty easily for this, just add the following CSS to your current file:

```
#blur {
    background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg);
    background-position: center center;
}
```

And the outcome would look like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #image {
                background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg);
                display:block;
                width:500px;
                height:500px;
                position:relative;
            }
            #blur {
                display:block;
                position:absolute;
                width: 300px;
                height:300px;
                top:50%;
                left:50%;
                background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/50/Montage_of_Toronto_7.jpg);
                background-position: center center;
                transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
                border-radius:150px;
                -webkit-filter:blur(10px); filter: blur(10px); -moz-filter:blur(30px); -ms-filter: blur(10px);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="image">
            <div id="blur"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So that means if I make the `#blur` a draggable item, I'll have to re-calculate the background image position each time?

Comment: I'm afraid so John

Comment: Oh i changed my question slightly.  In my `#image`, I made `background-size:cover;` and `width: 100%;` .  So now now the middle dot should blur different regions of the image as you re-size the window.  This will require a javascript solution then?

Comment: Let me juggle around with it tonight, pure CSS is probably cleaner

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```css
body {
            background: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=') no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
        }
        .blur {
            background: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1486723312829-f32b4a25211b?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=&bg=) no-repeat center center fixed;
            background-size: cover;
            overflow: hidden;
            filter: blur(13px);
            position: absolute;
            height: 300px;
            top: -50px;
            left: -50px;
            right: -50px;
            bottom: -50px;
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 100px;
        }
        .widget {
            border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
            border-radius: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .center {
            position: absolute;
            margin: auto;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
        }
        .text {
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }
        .text h1 {
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
            color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 100px;
            font-family: 'Lora', serif;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 38px;
        }
        .text p {
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
            margin-top: 0px;
            font-family: 'Lato', serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 22px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="widget center">
        <div class="blur"></div>
        <div class="text center">
        <h1 class="">Lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>sit amet ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```